# Style referenced by a spacebar code is not applied

Tags: html, css, meteor

I'm sorry for the title, I could not think of a better one. I am trying to style a table depending on the result of a function call.
In my HTML file, I have the following:

```
<tr class="customers-new {{result}}">  //result can be 'checked' or ''
```

In my CSS then:

```
tr.customers-new {
  td {
    cursor: default;
  }

  .checked {
    background: @light-color;
    cursor: default;
  }

}
```

The style is just not applied. I tried td.checked, too.

Comment: do you want to apply `. checked` css to `tr` or `td`?

Comment: just to td. I tried td.checked, too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you clarified you are trying to put CSS to `td`, you can put `td` inside `.checked` as below

```css
tr.customers-new {
  td {
    cursor: default;
  }
  &.checked {
    td {
      background: "red";
      cursor: default;
    }
  }
}
```

Compiled code

[image]

Comment: Thanks but it does not seem to help. I can see that the proper style name is used (customers-new checked) but the style is still not applied.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the cells/table. What if I wanted to style tr insted of td?

Comment: hey no I missed the extender `&`. Please try with updated code.  You can check the compiled SASS here as well https://www.sassmeister.com/. Just paste this code and see how it complies to CSS.

Comment: Unfortunately, still the same. When I tried to compile into CSS, it shows customers-new.checked. Is it correct to have there the dot? Because my HTML code uses customers-new {{result}}

Comment: EDIT: It works now, thanks! It did not work with "red" that I left in there.